# How to swap fields in a form, depending on radio button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a form which is composed of a couple partial views, and each view uses the same model. The model has some data annotations and validations (PhoneNumber, Email, Compare, etc).

At the top of the form are 2 radio buttons: New and Update. If the user selects New, I want to display the form fields with no values provided. For Update, I am pre-populating the fields. I want to toggle the forms using the radio buttons.

What I'm having trouble with is that there's a set of fields where the user must enter and re-enter the data (like a Policy#), and the client-side validation verifies that the fields are equal. That validation is failing, because the 2nd field in one partial view (New) is comparing against the first field in the other partial View (Update). How can I get around this?

I've tried disabling the fields on the inactive partial view, but the validation still runs.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: I've tried binding the model to the partial views as sections within the same form element. Switching the radio button selection toggles the disabled attribute on the inactive partial view using jQuery.
I want the pair of fields on the New section to validate without checking the pair on the Update section, but they are bound to the same model properties using Html.TextBoxFor